# what is the difference between like and visit on a facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

Some of the facebook pages has a visit count apart from like counter as shown in the snapshots

This is the page maintained by me, https://www.facebook.com/keralarecipe

image 1

This is another page having visit count, https://www.facebook.com/wpartist

image 2

What actually the visit counter is counting.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how Facebook counts visits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `visits` metric shown on the Facebook Page is the number of checkins made to this Page's location.

Have a look at the Graph Explorer query for your examples:

1)

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=keralarecipe%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Ccheckins%2Clikes&version=v2.1

```
{
  "id": "353392871360845", 
  "name": "Kerala food recipes", 
  "checkins": 1, 
  "likes": 11701
}
```

2)

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=wpartist%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname%2Ccheckins%2Clikes&version=v2.1

```
{
  "id": "554284091263282", 
  "name": "Wordpress Developer & Designer", 
  "checkins": 16, 
  "likes": 29412
}
```

Answer (score -1):

number of likes is the count of likes(on posts and pages there is a like hyperlink if you like something shared and click on like only then the count of like is increased)
whereas the number of visits is showing the count of people who have visited or opened the shared page or post.

Thanks

Comment: I tried visiting and opening the shared posts using different facebook Ids. But the visit count doesn't changes. Official page of BMW Page https://www.facebook.com/BMW doesn't have a single visit, That doesn't mean no one visited or opened their shared page or post.

Comment: That's an incorrect answer.